# Google Sheets QUERY with WHERE on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a Google Sheet table and I am stuck on a specific query I want to make

[Source Table pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7RZp.png)

I need to sort my Names by "Type" and by "ValueType".
I managed to sort them by "Type" with ease, but i'm stuck on the sort by "ValueType" part, because they are in columns, not lines and I can't manage to find a way to sort them by columns

My Query looks like this right now

> =QUERY(A1:G8; "SELECT * WHERE A='Type1'; 1)

I want it to look something like this :

> =QUERY(A1:G8; "SELECT * WHERE A='Type1' AND C1:G1='ValueType 1'"; 1)

Is it possible to do something like this, and if so, can you please tell me what is the syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet, and ideally a table showing the end result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`=QUERY(A1:G8; "SELECT * WHERE A='Type1' AND (C='"&C$1&"' or D='"&D$1&"') "; 1)`

adding `or X='"&X$1&"'` within the `()` where X is the next letter.

`'"&C$1&"'` is the value in cell `C$1` but you can adapt that for a different value on your sheet, or a fixed value using `C='xxx'`

Comment: This formula could work, but i'm going to regularly add new "Values" so i'll need to change my formula each time i add a value, which is going to take some time...

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the formula, or you can do it too (if the number of columns is not fixed)

```
=QUERY({A1:G8}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1='Type1' and (" & "Col"&arrayformula(TEXTJOIN("='ValueType 1' or Col",,column(C:G)))&"='ValueType 1' )", 1)
```

try just that sentence to understand how it has been built

```
="Col"&arrayformula(TEXTJOIN("='ValueType 1' or Col",,column(C:G)))&"='ValueType 1'"
```

Comment: Thank you, i understan how that works, going to try to implement it to my current table

Comment: Post your file if necessary, if you need some more help !